# TFS 2018 Update Assembly Info on GIT Repository

Tags: git, build, continuous-integration, azure-devops, cd

I want on every push i do to tfs git repository that the Assembly Info file (Assembly version) will change on the build process. I have a task on the build process that changes the AssemblyInfo.cs files, then i want to also push this changes to the master repository so that i can pull the changes from visual studio and see that the Assembly Info source file has changed as well.

Thank you.

Comment: That's not a question. What did you try? What is your problem?

Comment: What is the ultimate goal? only update the AssemblyInfo.cs  file? Why don't you update it directly and push the changes to  Git repository?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a **PowerShell task** to push the updated assembly files into the git repo. Detail as below:

#### 1.   Add a PowerShell task after the step `AssemblyInfo.cs` is changed

After the task which changes `AssemblyInfo.cs` file, add a PowerShell task with the version 2.*(preview).

[image]

#### 2.   Commit change the push to TFS git repo by PowerShell script

Use the script as below to commit and push changes:

```
$branch="$(Build.SourceBranch)".replace("refs/heads/","")
git add .  # Or use "git add /path/to/AssemblyInfo.cs" instead
git commit -m 'commit changes for AssemblyInfo.cs file'
git push origin HEAD:$branch
```

[image]

Now, after each build, the updated `AssemblyInfo.cs` file will be pushed into the TFS git repo.